# Storing and retrieving date stored in object using java.util.Calendar

Tags: java, oop

I need to store a birthdate within a "Person" class.
How can I access the date using a "Person" object if the date is being stored using java.util.Calendar?

I tried creating a get method, but then realised that java.util.Calendar is static. I then tried creating a birthdate wrapper class but once again had troubles returning the object.

Here is some of what I've got so far:

```
public class Person {
private String firstname;
private String surname;

public Person(String firstname, String surname, BirthdateWrapper birth)   {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.surname = surname;
    BirthdateWrapper birthday = birth;
}

public String getFirst(){
    return firstname;
}

public String getSurt(){
    return surname;
}

public BirthdateWrapper returnBirthObj() {
    return birthday;
}

}


import java.util.Calendar;

public class BirthdateWrapper {
private int day;
private int month;
private int year;

Calendar birthday = Calendar.getInstance();

public BirthdateWrapper(int day, int month, int year) {
    this.day = day;
    this.month = month;
    this.year = year;
    setBirth();
    }

private void setBirth() {
    birthday.set(year, month, day);
}

}
```

Comment: If you're using Java 8, forget about the crappy old `java.util.Calendar` and `java.util.Date`, and use the new and much better date and time classes in package `java.time` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using GregorianCalendar, you can use a constructor. Otherwise you'll need to create an instance of Calendar and then set each field manually:

```
public void testX() {
   ...
   // Using GregorianCalendar
   Calendar bday1 = new GregorianCalendar(2016, 0, 1);
   person.setBirthdate(bday1);

   // Using Calendar
   Calendar bday2 = Calendar.getInstance();
   bday2.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
   bday2.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
   bday2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1));
   person.setBirthdate(bday2);
   ...
}
```

See [GregorianCalendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) for other constructors you can use. You could also create your own `MyCalendar` class to create your own constructor.

Comment: Looks good. How can I store bday1 in Person? And how can I then return the object in my get method?

Comment: Add `private Calendar birthdate` to your Person class, then add getters and setters to set/return that field. If you're using Eclipse, you can right-click on your class and select `Source` > `Generate getters and setters...` after you add that field.

Comment: So can I pass bday1 to Person in my constructor and then assign it to "private Calendar birthdate <name>"?

Comment: Yes you can assign that field via a constructor. Just include `Calendar birthdate` as a parameter in your constructor, then inside the constructor, assign that value to `this.birthdate`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look at [Class Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

This abstract class provides functions to get `java.util.Date` from `Calendar` instance. Forexample,

`calendar.getTime();`

> How can I access the date using a "Person" object if the date is being
>   stored using java.util.Calendar

Suppose, this is the definition of your `Person`.

```
public class Person {
     private String name;
     ...
     public static Calendar birthDate; // since you specified it's static
     ...
     // accessors/mutators
}
```

`Person.birthDate.getTime();` will get you the date. But remember, I will recommend reading `Calendar` class since it has a lot of details about `set()`, `get()`, `add()`, `roll()` methods which really should be understood in order to get the real benefit from `Calendar`.

Hope I understood the question clearly and answered accordingly. Comment if I misunderstood.

Comment: I've been told to instantiate Calendar in my test class and then pass it to Person. How can this be done?

Comment: @MartinRand and Calendar object is public static in Person class?

Comment: You can instantiate a Calendar like; `Calendar.getInstance();` which will return the calendar instance with current date and time settings.

Comment: would that be an object?

Comment: Calendar.getInstance(); will return an Calendar object, yes.